# Filemaker Pro add entry for each selected record in another table

Tags: database, filemaker

I have two tables that are linked with a common field.  I am trying to set up a script or layout or whatever might work to achieve the following.
I need to be able to select certain records from table 1 and then have the program give me a view that will allow me to add an entry to table 2 for each of the selected records in table 1.  Table 2 has multiple fields that I want to complete just once for all of the selected records.
I am presuming that I need to set up a script with a loop but if someone could get me started with the basics, I would greatly appreciate it.  Or if there is a way to do it with a layout, that would be great too! Using Filemaker Pro 12.

Comment: This is rather difficult to follow. Please give your tables **meaningful** names and indicate which is "one" and which is "many" in the relationship. Knowing the purpose would also help; right now it sounds like you may want to duplicate some data, which is a no-no in a relational database.

Comment: I am not wanting to duplicate data.  This is a cattle management database.  Table 1 details the cattle with fields such as color, gender, etc. and has a unique id identifier for each cow/bull.  Table 2 is an Events table where I will enter events for a number of cattle.  Table 2 has a CattleID field which relates to id in Table 1.  I want to select multiple animals and be able to enter an event for each animal.

Comment: Table 1: id(unique), color, gender, age  Table 2: id(autogenerating,unique), cattleid(related to id of table 1), eventdate, event, notes

Comment: So ideally, I select the cattle in table 1, run the script and it opens a popup that allows me to enter the date, event, notes fields in the event table, then the script creates an event for each selected animal.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are describing a many-to-many relationship between Cattle and Events: each animal can have multiple related events; and an event can relate to more than one animal.

If this is correct, you will need a third *join* table to resolve the many-to-many relationship into two one-to-many relationships:

```
Cattle -< CattleEvents >- Events
```

The way this works, you enter the event's data **once** into the Event's table, then proceed to associate different animals with the event, by creating a join record in the CattleEvents table for each. The join table needs to contain (at least) fields for CattleID and EventID.

Unlike other RDBMSs, Filemaker also allows you to create a many-to-many relationship without a join table; you can define a CattleID field in the Events table as text and format it as a checkbox using a value list of CattleIDs. However, this "shortcut" has many shortcomings when it comes to summarizing and reporting. Another problem with this method is that you cannot record anything specific about the join: for example, with a join table you can not only record an event of vaccination affecting 46 selected animals; you can also record the individual dosage each animal received, by entering it into a field in the join table.

---

**ADDED:**

Once you have the desired found set in the Cattle table, move to the Events table, create a new record, then have a script do the following:

```
Set Variable [ $eventID ; Events::EventID ]
#
Go to Layout [ Cattle ]
Go to Record [ First ]
Loop
  Set Variable [ $cattleIDs ; List ( $cattleIDS ; Cattle::CattleID ) ]
  Go to Record [ Next ; Exit after last ]
End Loop
#
Go to Layout [ CattleEvents ]
Loop
  Set Variable [ $i ; $i + 1 ]
  Exit Loop If [ $i > ValueCount ( $cattleIDs ) ]
  New Record
  Set Field [ CattleEvents::EventID ; $eventID ]
  Set Field [ CattleEvents::CattleID ; GetValue ( $cattleIDs ; $i ) ]
End Loop
#
Go to Layout [ original layout ]
```

At the end of the script, you should find yourself back in the Events table, with all the cattle from the found set in the Cattle table appearing in the portal to CattleEvents (assuming you have placed such portal on the layout of Events). In that portal, you may add the specific data for each animal related to the event.

Comment: Actually I was thinking that each event, while it may have the same details, would be unique so that this would be a oneway join.  I might have two events that have identical details (vaccination, dosage, date, etc) but they would be unique because the cattleid and the event id would be different.  I have already established value list for some of the fields in the event table which should avoid the need for a third table.  One cow can have many events but they are still all unique records due to the unique identifier in the event table id field.

Comment: I am afraid you are saying two different things at the same time. If you have "two events that have identical details" then you actually have one event only. Breaking it into multiple records with all the "identical details" repeated would be creating the exact redundancy I tried to warn you about. The "two events" are not unique; only the participations in the (one) event are.

Comment: I see each event as specific to the cow.  Yes, I could make an events table and then link cattle to the event or I just could create a separate event record for each animal.  Making an event specific to the animal has advantages for me because I can add notes specific to the animal.  Maybe the use of the word event is confusing, perhaps action would be better.  While I might give 40 cattle the same shots, I would prefer to have 40 action records so that I can add any extra animal specific info if I want.

Comment: "*Making an event specific to the animal has advantages for me because I can add notes specific to the animal*" This is why you need both the join table and the Events table: the data that is specific to the event goes into the Events table and is recorded only once; the data that is specific to the join (i.e. the unique intersection of animal/event, such as the notes you describe) goes into the join table. At no point is the same data recorded in more than place - that is the basic tenet of a relational database.

Comment: Ok, so I have now have three tables (not totally convinced of the need but can see some benefit!!).  Cattle, Events, and CattleEvents.  Cattle ID links to Events/CattleID and CattleEvents/CattleID.  EventID links to CattleEvents/EventID.  So now I need to know how assign an Event to multiple cattle at once and autocreate the CattleEvents records.

Comment: How will you determine which cattle to assign to an event? Will you be selecting them one by one, or will you have some criteria to perform a find in the Cattle table?

Comment: I would prefer to start by filtering in the cattle table.  By the way, thanks for hanging in here with me on this - much appreciated!

Comment: I have added a script to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael - looks like exactly what I need. Will be loading data and trying out.